# Does the TFS Web Access task board display only the top 20 work items?

Tags: tfs, scrum, workitem, tfs-web-access

When using TFS 2012 Web Access to run the sprint using MSF Scrum 2.1, I find that it's difficult to use the task board. In Web Access, navigating to WORK | backlog | Product Backlog | board, it seems like only the top 20 PBIs & Bugs out of a query of *all* PBIs & Bugs across all areas & iterations. The full list of these PBIs and Bugs appears at WORK | backlog | Product Backlog | backlog items, but only the top 20 in the task board.

Is there any way to allow for more than 20 task board items, or to paginate it per group of 20, or to configure it to display the top 20 from a different query or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, it displays only 20 items marked as New, whereas all Approved and Committed tickets are rendered.

Comment: Also if the status is 'Done' it also limits to 20.  It's an exceptionally annoying feature and I hope there is a way to alter this 20 item limit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the New/Done columns are not able to be changed on-premise prior to TFS 2013.4, according to an answer to this [MSDN help question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7f725d1-d504-4d90-8996-64854a34e3f6/help-tfs-frustratingly-product-backlog-board-does-not-display-all-user-stories?forum=tfsworkitemtracking) which pointed at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh543813%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

> Q: Can I increase the number of work items that show up in the first or last column on a Kanban board?
>   A: For Visual Studio Online and with TFS 2013.4 update, you can. See Work from the Kanban board. For on-premises TFS deployment prior to TFS 2013.4, you can’t. The first and last columns are preset to display a maximum of 20 items.

(The "Work from the Kanban board" link in the original article comes pre-broken)